# Is there a way to get to all variables of a certain type in a class?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a Typescript class like

```
class MyClass {
     myNum1:number;
     myNum2:number;
     myNum3:number;
     myString:string;
     myBoolean:boolean;
}
```

Is there any way for to get all of the instance variables of type `number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code "compiles" to this:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

with nothing in there as you can see... however if you initialize your properties it will result some like this:

source TS:

```
class MyClass {
    myNum1: number = 0;
    myNum2: number = 0;
    myNum3: number = 0;
    myString: string = "";
    myBoolean: boolean = false;
}
```

result JS:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.myNum1 = 0;
        this.myNum2 = 0;
        this.myNum3 = 0;
        this.myString = "";
        this.myBoolean = false;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

then you can check instance properties:

```
var instance = new MyClass();
Object.keys(instance) //["myNum1", "myNum2", "myNum3", "myString", "myBoolean"]
instance["myNum1"] // 0
```

with that in mind you can filter the properties that you need:

```
var numerics = Object.keys(instance).map(k => instance[k]).filter(v => v.constructor === Number)
console.log(numerics) //[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Cool - I did not know about `.constructor.name`. That is very useful. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: How is `v.constructor.name === "Number"` different from `v.constructor === Number`?

Comment: @SantiagoHernández you mean like `constructor(...):any {}` ? I thought `constructors` can't return anything anyway

Comment: no, sorry, what I was trying to say is that `.constructor.name` will throw an error in typescript, so you need to do something like `(<any>v.constructor).name === "Number"` or `v.constructor === Number` in order to make it work